# Split with foldr in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to program a function `split` using `foldr`

```
split :: Eq a ⇒ a → [a] → [[ a ]]
```

Examples:

```
split '/' ”hello/my/friends” ----> [”hello”,”my”,”friends”]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
split :: Eq a ⇒ a → [a] → [[ a ]]
split str delim = let (start, end) = break (== delim) str
                in start : if null end then [] else groupBy (tail end) delim
```

Comment: Could you post any attempts you've made so far? With which part are you having difficulty?

Comment: all, I dont know programming this function.

Comment: @christianrusso Why do you need to express it as `foldr`, and is that the difficulty? Are you able to write `split` another way?

Comment: I can't use a explicit recursion

Comment: @christianrusso then you should at least write your code which uses explicit recursion. and then ask how to use `foldr`.

Comment: Does it have to be `foldr` or can it be `foldl`?

Comment: is the same. I can use foldl or foldr

Comment: @christianrusso - I've rolled your change back. Please don't completely alter the text of questions, especially after you've got answers - add a new question instead,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
foldr (\c (x:xs) ->
    if c == '/'
    then "":x:xs
    else (c:x):xs
  ) [""] "hello/my/friends"
```

Generalized:

```
split on = foldr (\c (x:xs) ->
    if c == on
    then []:x:xs
    else (c:x):xs
  ) [[]]
```

Comment: I use this function split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[ a ]]. And I have the follow error: Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Char’

Comment: '(c:x):xs` does not work. `c : x` would have type of `[a]`, but `: xs` expects type of `a`. Left associativity with `(:)` never works.

Comment: @Kwarrtz Except it *does* work. It's parenthesized. You *want* `c:x` to be of type `[a]`. `xs` is of type `[[a]]`.